# home page widget - product weird padding on hover

Tags: magento2, widget

I have the widget in my home page

```
{{widget type="Magento\CatalogWidget\Block\Product\ProductsList" title="" show_pager="0"
    products_count="6" template="Magento_CatalogWidget::product/widget/content/grid.phtml"
    conditions_encoded="^[`1`:^[`type`:`Magento||CatalogWidget||Model||Rule||Condition||Combine`,`aggregator`:`all`,`value`:`1`,`new_child`:``^]^]"}}
```

With the layout:
[image]

but when I hover, the layout gets weird like there's some padding:

[image]

I want it to remain the same. I added the green, yellow and pink colors to make it more clear. I've been trying to find what's the reason for the hovering but for the life of me I can't seem to get it to work. This is in the home page. The catalog product page works fine for the hovering.

test site:
https://testweb.ustrading.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay so I found the code:
there's a weird margin: -10px; and padding: 9px;

.products-grid .product-item-info:hover, .products-grid .product-item-info.active {
background: #ffffff;
background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
box-shadow: 3px 4px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
border: 1px solid #bbbbbb;
margin: -10px;
padding: 9px;
position: relative;
z-index: 9;
}

I just set the margin and padding to 0 and it's fixed!